# There's no way i can find this element (facebook_bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to build a facebook bot. But i'm unable to find an element.
The actual element (as you see it without looking into the html code) is in a window (is the window that shows when you are trying to sell something in facebook's marketplace). I have already found an element inside that window (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Artículo en venta")]').click()) so there is no problem with 'frames'

Here is the element code:

```
<input class="_58al" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_mq" aria-expanded="true" data-testid="searchable-text-input" role="combobox" placeholder="Selecciona una categoría" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="">
```

I have tried the following:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_st"]/input').click()
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Seleccione una categoría"]').click()
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input._58al').click()
 driver.find_element_by_link_text('Selecciona una categoría').click()
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Selecciona una categoría")]').click()
```

I'm using Linux Mint as my OS (if that mater)

The syntaxis may be wrong. If so feel free to correct me!
Any ideas will be aprecciate it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you checked the source code of the page to identify the correct path?

Comment: do you get any error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: create minimal working code so we could run it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on Python but I see irregularities with your locators.You can try below locator:

XPath:
You can choose any of the attribute value in place of Placeholder as well. Make Sure the Xpath is unique to your element.

```
//input[@placeholder='Selecciona una categoría']
```

You can use these locators in your python code.

Below are the reasons why I feel your locators where not working :

There is no ID attribute in your element code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_st"]/input').click()
```

The Single Quotes and Double quotes looks interchanged:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Seleccione una categoría"]').click()
```

Locator should be in Double Quotes:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input._58al').click()
```

The Element you are accessing is not a link as there was no href attribute :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Selecciona una categoría').click()
```

The Element also does not have text as per the above snippet:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Selecciona una categoría")]').click()
```